# Scrapy file after running gives no output but the selectors work in scrapy shell

Tags: python, scrapy

I have create a  spider, when i run the response.css on scrapy shell but when i run the spider it gives no o/p.
below is my code:

```
> import scrapy  class tapo(scrapy.Spider):
>     name="mapit"
>     start_urls=["https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter?schedule=results"]
>         def event_parse(self,response):
>         event_link=response.css('.name a::attr(href)').getall()
>         BASE_URL="https://www.tapology.com"
>         event_urls=self.BASE_URL+event_link
>         yield scrapy.Request(event_urls, callback=self.parse_attr)
>     def event_items(self,response):
>         event_name=response.css('.name a::text').getall()
>         event_dtm=response.css('.datetime::text').getall()
>         event_loc=response.css('.region a::text').getall()
>         yield{
>             'event_name':event_name,
>             'event_dtm':event_dtm,
>             'event_loc':event_loc
>         }
```

I run spider by typing > scrapy crawl mapit and this is what happens

```
2020-12-15 20:24:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: tapology1)
2020-12-15 20:24:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.1.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.1.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-12-15 20:24:28 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-12-15 20:24:28 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'tapology1',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tapology1.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tapology1.spiders']}
2020-12-15 20:24:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 56ccb4901a1e00f7
2020-12-15 20:24:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-12-15 20:24:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-12-15 20:24:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-12-15 20:24:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-12-15 20:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-12-15 20:24:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-12-15 20:24:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-12-15 20:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tapology.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-12-15 20:24:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter?schedule=results> (referer: None)
2020-12-15 20:24:31 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter?schedule=results> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 90, in _parse
    return self.parse(response, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 93, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError(f'{self.__class__.__name__}.parse callback is not defined')
NotImplementedError: tapo.parse callback is not defined
2020-12-15 20:24:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-12-15 20:24:31 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 478,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 26743,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.060803,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 14, 54, 31, 263134),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 14, 54, 29, 202331)}
2020-12-15 20:24:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

any ideas and tips on how to run spider are appreciated, I am new to scrapy, and i have seen on how to run it but probably am going somewhere wrong

edit: made corrections
what am i not seeing herre

```
2020-12-15 22:44:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter?schedule=results> (referer: None)
2020-12-15 22:44:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter?schedule=results> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\chaitali\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\Chaitali\scrapeit\tapology1\tapology1\spiders\tapogy.py", line 15, in parse
    event_urls=self.BASE_URL+event_link
AttributeError: 'tapo' object has no attribute 'BASE_URL'
2020-12-15 22:44:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-12-15 22:44:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 478,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 26935,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3.043361,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 17, 14, 39, 661997),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 15, 17, 14, 36, 618636)}
2020-12-15 22:44:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a method named `parse` in your spider because that's what Scrapy looks for to start the crawling process. `event_parse` could be renamed to `parse`, and assuming that the indentation errors shown in your question are not in your actual code, everything should be fine.

Also, for the yield, there are some other errors here. You used `getall()`, which returns a list. If you want to go to all the links made from that list, you must have the following code in your `parse` method.

```
BASE_URL = "https://www.tapology.com"
event_urls = []
for link in event_link:
    link = BASE_URL + link # BASE_URL is not an attribute of the spider, so do not use self.BASE_URL
    event_urls.append(link)

yield from response.follow_all(event_urls, callback=self.parse_attr)
```

In addition, make sure your `parse_attr` is defined, otherwise that callback to it won't work. If you want the response data from the yielded request to go to `event_items`, set that as the callback instead.

There are some shortcuts that can be made here, but since you're new to python and/or Scrapy, I tried to make things as explicit as possible.

Comment: i dont thinnk i have come across parse_attr . where do i use it

Comment: @Chai your `yield` in `event_parse` has the callback set to the `parse_attr` method. This may be a typo on your part. If you want the data in the response to go to `event_items`, then set that as the callback. I will edit my answer to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change `event_parse` to `parse`, and then your `callback` method to `parse`, should be fine:

```
 import scrapy  class tapo(scrapy.Spider):
>     name="mapit"
>     start_urls=["https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter?schedule=results"]
>         def parse(self,response):                                   # CORRECTED
>         event_link=response.css('.name a::attr(href)').getall()
>         BASE_URL="https://www.tapology.com"
>         event_urls=self.BASE_URL+event_link
>         yield scrapy.Request(event_urls, callback=self.parse)       # CORRECTED
>     def event_items(self,response):
>         event_name=response.css('.name a::text').getall()
>         event_dtm=response.css('.datetime::text').getall()
>         event_loc=response.css('.region a::text').getall()
>         yield{
>             'event_name':event_name,
>             'event_dtm':event_dtm,
>             'event_loc':event_loc
>         }
```

or if not fine, it should at least give output or a different error.

Now that you corrected the above, I think the new error is because of the way you are trying to create an `absolute url`.

```
event_link=response.css('.name a::attr(href)').getall() # why getall()? use line below
event_link=response.css('.name a::attr(href)').get()
event_urls=self.BASE_URL+event_link # change this
event_urls = BASE_URL+event_link # to this
```

Comment: just to be clear i run the spider like this> scrapy crawl mapit (i think it is giving the same error) also if i run the whole file as in run debug nothing happens either . (corrected the code)

Comment: Yes that's okay. And if you want to save it as a ```.csv```, you can do ```scrapy crawl mapit -o 'your_csv_name.csv'```

Comment: So now the code runs, but yields 0 output?

Comment: i edited the post . showing the error. also how do you know whats the error . i mean i barely understand .

Comment: I am not sure this will work, as I am not running the spider on my end, and I am personally using ```xpath``` expressions usually. But give it a go and let me know.